# Share file system NFS and S3 Bucket - That is better?

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, s3fs

I would like to share media folder of magento for multi server ( EC2 Instance) in VPC. 
Solution share file system by NFS is better or S3 bucket (use s3fs tool to mount from ec2) is better?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Hello Enigmativity, I think main problem of this question is not of magento. It's about aws service!

Comment: But it's not about programming so it is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

NFS is not available in all regions, so you need to consider that.  Also, NFS is more expensive than S3.

Comment: Thanks Chris Rouffer!. My instances in Singapore. I use one instance as nfs server ( i don't use EFS because EFS is not available in Singapore). I need the stability of the system. but i never use S3 bucket before.

Answer (score 0):

S3 will likely provide the most durability for you, as well as being one of the cheapest solutions when only factoring in cost of storage. Total cost of ownership may be higher, depending on your needs for the data being stored.

That being said, s3fs has a history of performance issues. Many of these have been resolved over the last couple of years, however using s3fs will remain slower than using NFS.

I know little about Magento - I've never worked on it - but you may want to investigate this package, which purports to support syncing the media folder to s3: https://packagist.org/packages/arkade/magento-s3

Using S3 directly via the APIs from your application would be vastly preferable to hitting it via s3fs.

Comment: Thanks Luke Waite, I will try it!